# Scroll to position on another page when links already have anchor to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this menu on `home page` that scrolls to the `id` positions:

```
<li><a href="#event-section">El evento</a></li>
<li><a href="#asistentes-section">Asistentes</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact-section">Contacto & Inscripciones</a></li>
```

I'm using this script for the smooth scrolling:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

This works perfectly.

The problem is that I have another page in the site. When the user enters to it and click on any link of the menu, it just doesn't work since the `divs` exists only on `home page`. I want that if the user is in this other page and clicks on a link of the menu then the `home page` opens going to that section.

Any idea how can I fix this menu to be able to do both things?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding index.html then hash like below in all other pages except homepage. This should work.

```html
<li><a href="index.html#event-section">El evento</a></li>
```

Comment: This just reloads the page adding the `#` to the URL and without going to the `homepage`

Comment: Did you try to load script on document.ready(function())? Otherwise try third party plugins like fullpage.js :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script, Need to dynamic means to get the hash url scrolldown to there.
Example:

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf('#event-section') > -1) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $("a[href='#event-section']").offset().top
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
    });
}
</script>
```

This is for first link page as index.html#event-section.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to create another nav bar for other page from where you want to redirect your end users

```
<li><a href="/index.php?id=event-section">El evento</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id=asistentes-section">Asistentes</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id=contact-section">Contacto & Inscripciones</a></li>
```

and on your `home page` run this `script`

```
<script>

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
    var param_scroll = getParameterByName('id');
    if(param_scroll){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+param_scroll).offset().top
        }, 3000);   
    }
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery not required if you implemented this fucntion:

```
function scrollTo(anchorName) {
    location.hash = "#" + anchorName;
    return false;
}
```

in this case you link should be:

```
<a href="#anchorName">my_link</a>
```

Comment: This just reloads the page adding the `#` to the URL and without going to the `homepage` specific section

Comment: @propcode you should ```return false;``` from this function that page not reloaded